# Closing tags are not being executed

Tags: pagination, ajax, html

I'm loading a template with ajax and I'm trying to close a few divs and a section in which the opening tags are in a different file. The closing tags aren't being recognized on the front-end, while it is recognized when I simply type something like 'test' where I now close the tags.

How can I make it recorgnize the closing tags?

```
    {paginate}
            {pagination_links}
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
                {next_page}
                    <div class="loadmore">
                        <p>Laad meer...</p>
                        <a href="{pagination_url}" id="load_more"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></a>
                    </div>
                {/next_page}
            {/pagination_links}
        {/paginate}
```

Edit:

So this is the main template:

```
    {layout="_layouts/vervolg"}

{layout:set name="main_content"}
<div class="all-projects">
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="projects">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <h1>WIJ WERKTEN EERDER AAN<span class="blue"> DEZE PROJECTEN</span></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row_projects">
                <div id="portfolio_loader">
                    <div class="progress">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%">
                            <span class="sr-only">Laden...</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="portfolio">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

</div>
{/layout:set}
```

I'm loading the ajax in the  tag. In order to make my template look okay, the load more button should be placed directly under the  tag, but because the load more button is in the ajax template in order for it to work, it's not in the template above but in the ajax template right here:

```
    <script>
    $( "#load_more" ).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var url = $('#load_more').attr('href');

        $.ajax({url: url, success: function(result){
            $("#portfolio").append(result);
        }});

        $('.loadmore').remove();
    });
</script>

                {exp:channel:entries
                    channel="portfolio"
                    dynamic="no"
                    limit="1"
                    paginate="bottom"
                    paginate_base="/ajax/{segment_2}"
                    disable="categories|member_data"
                }
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 portfolio-item">
                    <div class="square_box">
                        <div class="square-box">
                            <div class="overlay"><a href="{page_url}">{exp:ce_img:single src="{portfolio_afbeelding}" class="img-square img-responsive" crop="yes" width="330" height="264"}</a></div>
                            <h4>{title}</h4>
                            <h6><strong>Velg:</strong> {portfolio_velg}.</h6>
                            {exp:streeng characters="100" append="&nbsp;- <a href='{page_url}'>Lees verder</a>"}
                            {portfolio_content}
                            {/exp:streeng}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


        {paginate}
            {pagination_links}
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
                {next_page}
                    <div class="loadmore">
                        <p>Laad meer...</p>
                        <a href="{pagination_url}" id="load_more"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></a>
                    </div>
                {/next_page}
            {/pagination_links}
        {/paginate}

    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

As stated below however, the  and  tags aren't being recognized here and are being closed in my 'main' template instead of in the ajax template. To be clear: removing the closing tags in my 'main' template doesn't make a difference.

Comment: If there are not enough entries for pagination to fire, then you 3 closing div tags and the section tag will not display.  Why  not put them just above the paginagte tag?  Opening tags in one template and closing them in another is a good way to drive yourself crazy.

Comment: @JimWyse I'm aware of that. The point is that the tags aren't closing either way. Not even if I put them outside the whole channel entries tag.

Comment: That being the case, can you put up simplified code along with Ajax call so we can have a more complete picture pls.

Comment: @stuartmcd69 I editted my question

Answer (score 0):

Here, You can call default template as EE embed and use the same for ajax load. This will definitely help. (As I didn't tested the code, You may need to have some changes on code below)

**Main template code:**

```
{layout="_layouts/vervolg"}

{layout:set name="js"}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('click', '.load_more', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.load_more').addClass('temp');

            var url = $('.load_more').attr('href');
            $.ajax({url: url, success: function(result){
                $("#portfolio").append(result);
            }});

            $('.temp').remove();
        });
    </script>
{/layout:set}

{layout:set name="main_content"}
<div class="all-projects">
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="projects">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <h1>WIJ WERKTEN EERDER AAN<span class="blue"> DEZE PROJECTEN</span></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row_projects">
                <div id="portfolio_loader">
                    <div class="progress">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%">
                            <span class="sr-only">Laden...</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="portfolio">
                    {!--Load file by default--}
                    {embed="ajax/my-file"}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

</div>
{/layout:set}
```

**Ajax Template code: (That is embed on load and then trigger via ajax every time)**

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="portfolio"
    dynamic="no"
    paginate="bottom"
    disable="categories|member_data"
    limit="1"
}
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 portfolio-item">
        <div class="square_box">
            <div class="square-box">
                <div class="overlay"><a href="{page_url}">{exp:ce_img:single src="{portfolio_afbeelding}" class="img-square img-responsive" crop="yes" width="330" height="264"}</a></div>
                <h4>{title}</h4>
                <h6><strong>Velg:</strong> {portfolio_velg}.</h6>
                {exp:streeng characters="100" append="&nbsp;- <a href='{page_url}'>Lees verder</a>"}
                {portfolio_content}
                {/exp:streeng}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {paginate}
        {pagination_links}
        {next_page}
            <div class="loadmore">
                <p>Laad meer...</p>
                <a href="{pagination_url}" class="load_more"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></a>
            </div>
        {/next_page}
        {/pagination_links}
    {/paginate}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: I know that, I've tried this already. The opening tags however are not on this page. They're in a different template. Closing the tags this way is not working. It doesn't matter where I put the tags, they're simply not closing.

Comment: Are you loading data via ajax?

Comment: Yes I am. The template I'm showing you is the ajax template

Comment: Ok. Can you edit your question and put main page and ajax page code both and describe little bit why would you need end  divs in ajax template inside pagination?

Comment: I updated the question. I hope this clears it up for you.

Comment: I got it. As HTML build the template on page read time, It will close the divs not found by HTML. So removing ending divs will take no effect.  You need to close the divs on page load for sure. I have updated my answer, hope it helps you.